# Component Unit Testing in Ionic 3 using Jasmine-Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, ionic3, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a page in Ionic 3. So, I created .spec.ts of that page manually within src/pages/page folder. But when I create component using TestBed.createComponent, then it shows following error :

[image]

> about.spec.ts file

```
    import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { AboutPage } from './about';
import { IonicPageModule, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule,platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('AboutPage', () => {

    let fixture;
    let component;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AboutPage ],
        imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage)],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        providers: [NavController, NavParams, Platform]
      }).compileComponents().then((response) => {
          fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);
          component = fixture.componentInstance;
          fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    }));

    afterEach(() => {
      fixture.destroy();
      component = null;
    });

     describe('First test',() => {
        it('should print',() => {
            let a = true;
            expect(a).toBeTruthy();
        })
    })
});
```

I am unable to find out where my code is lacking due to which this error is coming. I need to fetch component in my spec file so as to perform testing on its functions and its part.
     Please suggest where I may be doing wrong.

> **AS SUGGESTED (Edition-1) :**

I changed my about.spec.ts by removing afterEach and refactoring beforeEach code into 2 parts :

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture, async } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { AboutPage } from './about';
import { IonicPageModule, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule,platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

describe('AboutPage', () => {

    let fixture;
    let component;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ AboutPage ],
            imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage)],
            schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [NavController, NavParams, Platform]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should print',() => {
        let a = true;
        expect(a).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

But again I am getting same type of error, not that of destroy one.

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from `fixture.destroy()` inside `afterEach` function because `fixture` is `undefined`.

You can get rid of this `afterEach` function since `fixture` and `component` are supposed to be created for each test again inside the `beforeEach` function. To make this really happen, also try to split the `beforeEach` into two functions same as found in [CLI-generated tests](https://angular.io/guide/testing#cli-generated-tests).

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AboutPage ],
        imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(AboutPage)],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
        providers: [NavController, NavParams, Platform]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AboutPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: Thankyou @uminder for your time and suggestion. But I am getting same type of error. The changes that I made on the basis of your answer, are there under **AS SUGGESTED (Edition-1) :** quote in my description. Please suggest.